# Doctrine2: YEAR, MONTH, DAY or DATE_FORMAT for PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, doctrine-orm, symfony4

Since neither `DAY()`, `MONTH()`, `YEAR()`, nor `DATE_FORMAT()` are available in Doctrine2, how can you use one of these functions in Query Builder, when using a PostgreSQL database?

I found several tutorials, but they all apply to MySQL, none to PostgreSQL.

Comment: can you instead extract the timestamp into a php object and use php's (albeit inferior) timestamp manipulation tools to accomplish your goal?

Comment: Sure you can do it in PHP. But you can't use `->groupBy('year')` in this case (see example below).

Answer (score 6):

Since the SQL syntax differs between database vendors, it's not possible (or at least not so easy) to create a vendor-independent solution. So here's a way for PostgreSQL.

The SQL function we're going to use is `to_char()`, see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-formatting.html

First we need to create a Custom DQL Function, see https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/cookbook/dql-user-defined-functions.html

```
namespace App\DQL;

use Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\FunctionNode;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\SqlWalker;

class ToChar extends FunctionNode
{
    public $timestamp = null;
    public $pattern = null;

    // This tells Doctrine's Lexer how to parse the expression:
    public function parse(Parser $parser)
    {
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_IDENTIFIER);
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_OPEN_PARENTHESIS);
        $this->timestamp = $parser->ArithmeticPrimary();
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_COMMA);
        $this->pattern = $parser->ArithmeticPrimary(); // I'm not sure about `ArithmeticPrimary()` but it works. Post a comment, if you know more details!
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS);
    }

    // This tells Doctrine how to create SQL from the expression - namely by (basically) keeping it as is:
    public function getSql(SqlWalker $sqlWalker)
    {
        return 'to_char('.$this->timestamp->dispatch($sqlWalker) . ', ' . $this->pattern->dispatch($sqlWalker) . ')';
    }
}
```

Then we register it in Symfony 4, see https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/custom_dql_functions.html

```
# config/packages/doctrine.yaml

doctrine:
    orm:
        dql:
            string_functions:
                to_char: App\DQL\ToChar
```

Now we can use it in any Repository:

```
return $this->createQueryBuilder('a')
    ->select("to_char(a.timestamp, 'YYYY') AS year")
    ->groupBy('year')
    ->orderBy('year', 'ASC')
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult()
;
```